# Python 3.7, Change button's colour when it's down

Tags: python, button, kivy

How do I change the button's color when it's down? As in, when you press the button, replace the blue-ish colour into another one?

I've tried fiddling around with background_color_down, background_color_normal, I tried using canvas and the sort but nothing seems to have the effect I intend it to

Comment: You could have the function that is called by the button press change the colour of the button directly.

Answer (score 0):

Or you could try giving the path to a png file with your design of the pressed button to the background_down attribute. Here my file is called "pressed.png" and is located within the same folder as the python programm. [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l0jUE.png) is a link to something i made within 30 seconds in inkscape.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.5
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty, ListProperty
from kivy.atlas import Atlas

kv= Builder.load_string('''
<MainScreen>
    my_but:my_but
    orientation: "vertical"
    size_hint:1,1
    # size_hint: 0.3,0.3
    # pos_hint:{"center_x": 1, "center_y":1}
    Label:
        size_hint: 0.5,0.4
        text: "Look at my Button go:"
    Button:
        id:my_but
        size_hint: 0.5,0.4
        text: "klick me"
        # background_normal: ""
        background_down: "pressed.png"
''')
class MainScreen(BoxLayout):
    my_but = ObjectProperty(None)
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MainScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)


class myApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MainScreen()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    myApp().run()
```